# Does MariaDB-Galera Cluster support LAST_INSERT_ID and mysql_info?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-cluster

As far as I understand, Galera does not support table locking, but what information can be retrieved about the last query?

> LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES cannot be supported in master-master replication. Lock functions (GET_LOCK(), RELEASE_LOCK(),…) are not supported.

What about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?  At some point I read, that the nodes use different auto increment values, but it said nothing whether the last insert id will be returned.

And a related question: In PHP I use the `mysql_info` function to retrieve the "rows matched" on `UPDATE`.  Is this information expected to be availible in a Galera cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but yet both are supported just as they are in standard mysql.